# ccyymmddhhmmss format for shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, txt

How to create text files with date and time as per below format:

vendor_brandname_ccyymmddhhmmss.txt

currently I am using below format:

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
file1=HospTOHome_BRC_$DATE.txt

Comment: It's not clear what your actual question is; perhaps a different duplicate would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` argument isn't limited to *just* placeholders.

```
$ date +"HsopTOHome_BRC_%Y%m%d%H%M%S.txt"
HsopTOHome_BRC_20210630082847.txt
```

You can set the value of `file1` with a command substitution:

```
$ file1=$(date ...)
```

To actually *create* the file, you can use `touch`:

```
$ touch "$file1"
```

or redirection the output of some command that generates the contents you want:

```
$ ls > "$file"
```

or pass it as the argument to your favorite text editor:

```
$ vi "$file"
```